# Upstart Logrotate?

Tags: logs, configuration, logrotate, upstart

What's wrong with my config? I had to --force the logrotate a couple times to see changes, but the numbering is all wonky.

```
    ----@----------:/var/log/upstart# ls -Anh
    total 4.0G
    -rw-r----- 1 0 0  56K Aug 21 08:41 graylog-server.log
    -rw-r----- 1 0 0 1.1G Aug 21 08:36 graylog-server.log.1.1.gz
    -rw-r----- 1 0 0 727M Aug 21 08:35 graylog-server.log.1.gz.1.gz
    -rw-r----- 1 0 0    0 Aug 20 11:22 graylog-server.log.2.gz
    -rw-r----- 1 0 0  28K Aug 20 10:40 graylog-server.log.3.gz.1.gz
    -rw-r----- 1 0 0 1.2G Aug 20 10:29 graylog-server.log.4.gz.1
    -rw-r----- 1 0 0 861M Aug 21 08:40 graylog-server.log.4.gz.1.gz
    -rw-r----- 1 0 0 212M Aug 20 10:25 graylog-server.log.5.gz
    -rw-r----- 1 0 0 5.3M Aug 20 06:25 graylog-server.log.6.gz
```

Config:

```
----@----------:/var/log/upstart# vim /etc/logrotate.d/upstart

/var/log/upstart/*-server.log.* {
        size 3G
        missingok
        rotate 5
        compress
        notifempty
        nocreate
}
```

Using logrotate

> --force /etc/logrotate.d/upstart

to rotate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are log-rotating already log-rotated logs.

In your config you use `/var/log/upstart/*-server.log.*` to select the files to rotate. This expression matches `graylog-server.log.1` but no `graylog-server.log`. So you are rotating the old rotated log files but not the current log file.

Probably you want to use `/var/log/upstart/*-server.log` instead.

Comment: Ok, I'll give that a try. I also wanted to ask how often the system checks for the size condition...like if it has to sit at 3GB for a couple hours before it'll rotate or if it happens instantly? edit: that does fix the file extension issue.

Comment: @KuboMD ask this in another question.

Comment: I tried making that change to the conf and running the logrotate force again. It works the first time around, but the second time around it adds a ".1" to the end of my plaintext, uncompressed log - which means it is no longer caught by "*-server.log". Any suggestions?

Comment: Fascinating. Did you cleaned the dir of old wrong files before you tried again?

Comment: There is no reason (in your config file) for that `.1`. Please, check if there is any other rule in logrotate config files matching that log file.

Comment: Thanks andcoz, I did check those. I added the "copy" keyword which leaves the original filename alone - which is good, but it doesn't empty the contents of the original, which is bad. These configs are so confusing.